# Any website that explains most of the BIPs in a different way that newbies can understand better?

Tags: bip

Almost everything about all the BIPs is explained on github : https://github.com/bitcoin/bips still looking for a website that explains them differently (simple language, diagrams, history, implementations, etc. which everyone can understand better and appreciate the importance of proposals in Bitcoin.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of one comprehensive write-up, but Aaron van Wirdum has a few great write-ups of various proposals in Bitcoin Magazine, the Bitcoin Optech newsletter has covered a number of the more recent proposals in depth, there are a number of talks (and transcripts of those) about BIPs on Youtube from conferences, workshops and Bitcoin meetups. There are a few BIPs that have their own tags here where they are covered more in depth, but again, I don't know about a single resource that is just focused on explaining all the BIPs. Maybe someone should start one? :D

Until then, our site here is a great place to ask all your questions about any BIPs.

Comment: Thanks. I was planning to make one in my free time if there is no such website.

Comment: Started working on a website: https://bips.gallery GitHub: https://github.com/prayank23/BIPsGallery Tweet thread: https://twitter.com/prayankgahlot/status/1322254155071680512